# Which permissions should be for symfony 3 folders and files?

Tags: php, symfony, permissions, file-permissions

I've reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 and after getting pull my symfony 3.4 project from git, it loads but without CSS and JS. I think that the problem with the permissions for folders and files.

Comment: maybe your project is using something like `webpack` or `gulp` to generate those assests

Comment: Have you done your composer update? From project folder do the following, composer update --prefer-dist --profile -vvv then add your Symfony permissions.

Comment: How do you determine what is missing? Have a look at the source code: do you load CSS? Have a look at the network tab: is the CSS loaded properly? If not: is there any error involved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's permissions related, then first make sure of which user is your web user.
If you never changed it, then it's `www-data`

As for the permissions, do this (replace `www-data` if needed):

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/
find /var/www/ -type d -exec chmod 0775 "{}" \;
find /var/www/ -type f -exec chmod 0664 "{}" \;
find /var/www -type d -exec chmod g+s "{}" \;
```

**[Warning]**

In some projects like symfony, some files have the execution permission.
Doing this will remove the permission.

Thus, I recommand to move all your projects out of the `/var/www` folder before doing this.
When done with permissions, just copy (not move) your projects in the `/var/www` folder, they will inherit web user and web group (www-data in this case) and keep execution permission.

**[Side note]**

You're using too many tags.
`file-permissions, symfony, ubuntu` should have been enough... ;)