# Files are not uploading to upload directory?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.2

I am trying to upload files from a form and then save it in a directory **uvis_front_user_files** which is located under **web/uploads** but when i save the form everything goes well but the files are not there in the destination directory.

Even the file name is saved in **database** but in the **uvis_front_user_files** directory there is nothing.

**Form**:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">   
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="heading heading-tertiary heading-border text-center">
        <h4 class="heading-tertiary"><?php echo $quiz['title'] ?></h4>
        <p><?php echo $quiz['description'] ?></p>
      </div>
      <?php if ($sf_user->hasFlash('success')): ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success">
          <?php echo $sf_user->getFlash('success'); ?>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <?php echo $form->renderGlobalErrors(); ?>
          <table class="sample-order-frm" width="100%">
            <?php echo $form['name']->renderRow() ?>
            <?php echo $form['email']->renderRow() ?>
            </tr>
          </table>
            <?php $current = current($quiz['questions']) ?>
        <?php if ($current["text"] !== NULL): ?>
          <h4 class="heading-tertiary">Please leave blank the questions that do not apply:</h4>
          <ol class="survey-ques-list">
            <?php foreach ($quiz['questions'] as $questionId => $question): ?>
                <li>
                <label><?php echo $question['text']; ?></label>
                <?php echo $form['question_'.$questionId]->render(); ?>
                <?php echo $form['path']->render(); ?>
                <?php echo $form['question_'.$questionId]->renderError(); ?>
              </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
          </ol>
          <br />
        <?php endif; ?>
          <?php echo $form->renderHiddenFields(false); ?>
          <div class="text-center">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-tertiary btn-lg"/>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Action File:

```
<?php

/**
 * uvisQuiz actions.
 *
 * @package    we.com
 * @subpackage uvisQuiz
 * @version    SVN: $Id: actions.class.php 12479 2008-10-31 10:54:40Z fabien $
 */
class uvisQuizActions extends sfActions {

  /**
   * Executes index action
   *
   * @param sfRequest $request A request object
   */
  public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request) {
    $this->forward404Unless($slug = $request->getParameter('slug'));
    $this->forward404Unless($this->quiz = UvisQuizFrontPeer::getQuizBySlug($slug));

    $this->form = new UvisQuizCustomForm(null, array('questions' => $this->quiz['questions']));

    if($request->isMethod('POST')){
      $params = $request->getParameter($this->form->getName());
      $this->form->bind($params, $request->getFiles($this->form->getName()));
      //$this->form->bind($params);
      if($this->form->isValid()){
        $uvisQuizUserObj = UvisQuizFrontPeer::saveQuiz($this->quiz, $params);
        $this->getUser()->setFlash('completed_video_survey', true);
        $this->redirect('@uvis_quiz_complete?slug='.$request->getParameter('slug'));
      }
    }
  }

  public function executeComplete(sfWebRequest $request) {
    $this->forward404Unless($slug = $request->getParameter('slug'));
    $this->forward404Unless($this->singleQuiz = UvisQuizFrontPeer::getQuizBySlug($slug));
    $this->forward404Unless($this->getUser()->hasFlash('completed_video_survey'));
  }
}
```

UvisQuizFrontPeer:

```
<?php

class UvisQuizFrontPeer extends BaseUvisQuizPeer {

  public static function getQuizBySlug($slug) {
    $criteria = new Criteria();
    $criteria->addSelectColumn('uvis_quiz.id as id');
    $criteria->addSelectColumn('uvis_quiz.title as title');
    $criteria->addSelectColumn('uvis_quiz.description as description');
    $criteria->addSelectColumn('uvis_quiz.path as path');

    $criteria->addSelectColumn('uvis_quiz_question.id as question_id');
    $criteria->addSelectColumn('uvis_quiz_question.question as question_text');
    $criteria->addSelectColumn('uvis_quiz_question.answer_type as answer_type');

    $criteria->addSelectColumn('uvis_quiz_question_answer.id as answer_id');
    $criteria->addSelectColumn('uvis_quiz_question_answer.answer as answer_text');

    $criteria->addJoin(self::ID, UvisQuizQuestionPeer::QUIZ_ID, Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);
    $criteria->addJoin(UvisQuizQuestionPeer::ID, UvisQuizQuestionAnswerPeer::QUIZ_QUESTION_ID, Criteria::LEFT_JOIN);

    $criteria->add(self::SLUG, $slug);
    $criteria->add(self::DELETED_AT, null, Criteria::ISNULL);
    $criteria->add(UvisQuizQuestionPeer::DELETED_AT, null, Criteria::ISNULL);
    $criteria->add(UvisQuizQuestionAnswerPeer::DELETED_AT, null, Criteria::ISNULL);

    $records = self::doSelectStmt($criteria)->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    $quizData = array();

    foreach ($records as $record) {
      if (!isset($quizData['id'])) {
        $quizData['id'] = $record['id'];
        $quizData['title'] = $record['title'];
        $quizData['description'] = $record['description'];
        $quizData['path'] = $record['path'];
        $quizData['questions'] = array();
      }

      if (!isset($quizData['questions'][$record['question_id']])) {
        $quizData['questions'][$record['question_id']]['text'] = $record['question_text'];
        $quizData['questions'][$record['question_id']]['type'] = $record['answer_type'];
        $quizData['questions'][$record['question_id']]['answer_choices'] = array();
        $quizData['questions'][$record['question_id']]['answers'] = array();
      }

      if (!isset($quizData['questions'][$record['question_id']]['answers'][$record['answer_id']])) {
        $quizData['questions'][$record['question_id']]['answer_choices'][$record['answer_id']] = $record['answer_text'];
        $quizData['questions'][$record['question_id']]['answers'][$record['answer_id']]['text'] = $record['answer_text'];
      }
    }

    return count($quizData) > 0 ? $quizData : false;
  }

  public static function saveQuiz($quizData, $params) {
    $uvisQuizUserObj = new UvisQuizUser();
    $uvisQuizUserObj->setQuizId($quizData['id']);
    $uvisQuizUserObj->setName($params['name']);
    $uvisQuizUserObj->setEmail($params['email']);
    $uvisQuizUserObj->save();

    foreach ($quizData['questions'] as $questionId => $question) {
      if(isset($params['question_'.$questionId]) && $params['question_'.$questionId] != ''){
        $uvisQuizUserAnswerObj = new UvisQuizUserAnswer();
        $uvisQuizUserAnswerObj->setQuizUserId($uvisQuizUserObj->getId());
        $uvisQuizUserAnswerObj->setQuiestionId($questionId);
        if($question['type'] == 'free_text'){
          $uvisQuizUserAnswerObj->setFreeTextAnswer($params['question_'.$questionId]);
          $uvisQuizUserAnswerObj->setPath($params['path']);
        }
        else{
          $uvisQuizUserAnswerObj->setAnswerId($params['question_'.$questionId]);
        }
        $uvisQuizUserAnswerObj->save();
      }
    }
    return $uvisQuizUserObj;
  }

}
```

QuizCustomForm:

```
<?php

class UvisQuizCustomForm extends sfForm {

  public function configure() {
    $mimeTypes = array('application/pdf', 'application/x-pdf', 'application/rtf',
          'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text', 'application/msword',
          'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet',
          'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document',
          'application/x-msword', 'text/plain');
    $this->widgetSchema['name'] = new sfWidgetFormInput(array(), array('class' => 'form-control'));
    $this->widgetSchema['email'] = new sfWidgetFormInput(array(), array('class' => 'form-control'));
    $this->widgetSchema['phone'] = new sfWidgetFormInput();

    $this->validatorSchema['name'] = new sfValidatorString(array('max_length' => 64, 'required' => true, 'trim' => 'both'), array('required' => 'Name is required', 'max_length' => 'Maximum %max_length% characters allowed'));
    $this->validatorSchema['email'] = new sfValidatorEmail(array('max_length' => 255, 'required' => true, 'trim' => 'both'), array('required' => 'Email is required', 'max_length' => 'Maximum %max_length% characters allowed', 'invalid' => 'Invalid email'));
    $this->validatorSchema['phone'] = new sfValidatorRegex(array('pattern' => '/^[0-9\-]+$/', 'required' => false), array('invalid' => 'Invalid phone number'));

    foreach ($this->options['questions'] as $questionId => $question) {
      if($question['type'] == 'multiple'){
        $this->widgetSchema['question_' . $questionId] = new sfWidgetFormChoice(array('choices' => $question['answer_choices'], 'expanded' => true));
        $this->validatorSchema['question_' . $questionId] = new sfValidatorChoice(array('required' => false, 'choices' => array_keys($question['answer_choices'])), array('invalid' => 'Invalid option selected'));
      } else {

      $this->widgetSchema['path'] = new sfWidgetFormInputFile(array(
          'label' => 'Upload File',
      ));
      $this->setValidator('path', new sfValidatorFile(array(
          'required'   => false,
          'path'       => sfConfig::get('sf_upload_dir').'/uvis_front_user_files',
          'mime_types' => $mimeTypes,
      )));
        $this->widgetSchema['question_' . $questionId] = new sfWidgetFormTextarea(array(), array('cols' => 50, 'rows' => 4));
        $this->validatorSchema['question_' . $questionId] = new sfValidatorString(array('required' => false));
      }
    }

    $this->widgetSchema['quiz_user_id'] = new sfWidgetFormInputHidden();
    $this->validatorSchema['quiz_user_id'] = new sfValidatorPropelChoice(array('model' => 'UvisQuizUser', 'column' => 'id', 'required' => false));

    $decorator = new sfWidgetFormSchemaFormatterMain($this->widgetSchema, $this->validatorSchema);
    $this->widgetSchema->addFormFormatter('custom', $decorator);
    $this->widgetSchema->setFormFormatterName('custom');

    $this->widgetSchema->setNameFormat('UvisQuizFrontForm[%s]');
  }

}
```

Comment: [Check your files permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48501277/which-permissions-should-be-for-symfony-3-folders-and-files/48501594#48501594) and here is a full detail on [file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38942760/file-upload-with-symfony3-not-working/38945180#38945180) in case you forgot something

Comment: @Preciel it's 1.2 version

Comment: Oh~ My bad... Quite rare to stay on such old versions... The file permissions part is still valid though

Comment: @Preciel ya it's client website, old version

Answer (score 0):

Just give write permission to the folder and check