# Uploading a file from url

Tags: php, file, symfony, upload

Hello guys :) how can i upload a file from an url ? (i read a lot of questions talking of this but nothing its working ...) here is my code :

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';

$file = file_get_contents($url);
if ($file != NULL) {
    $fileName = md5(uniqid()) . '.' . $file->guessExtension();

    $file->move(
        $this->getParameter('image_directory'), $fileName
    );
}
```

Here i just want to download the image from url and move it to a directory (i will save the path in the database after), but with this code i have this error :

> Call to a member function guessExtension() on string

Comment: Oh I see, Sorry my bad. Removed ; )

Comment: Symfony 3.4 vs 4 ... and he is using an form and i am using url not the same at all ...

Comment: `$file` will be the image you download. That is not an Object and therefore obviously it will not have any methods, hence the error when you try and use the non-existant `$file->guessExtension()` method

Comment: Why do you need to guess the extension anyway. You used the extension in the URL

Comment: I have this error ... Call to a member function move() on string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This simple code will download and save the image to a file

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';

$file = file_get_contents($url);


if ($file != NULL) {
    $pathToFolder = 'images/png/';        // just an example folder location
    $fileName = $pathToFolder . md5(uniqid()) . 'png';
    file_put_contents($fileName,$file);
} else {
    echo 'File downlaod error';
}
```

Comment: Uncomment the line I left commented when I tested it and comment the line below it

Comment: because there is no error but i don't know how to "create" the file and move it to my directory '/image'

Comment: There you go, just amended the code again. Just add the location of where you want to put the file into the `$fileName` variable, and the `file_put_contents` will do the rest

Answer (score 1):

`file_get_contents` is to read the content of a file (txt, xml, etc).
Instead, you should use linux command `wget`. You can run it with PHP function `exec`.

```
$url = 'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png';

//Execute wget
$file=exec("wget http://www.example.com/file.xml");
if ($file != NULL) {
    $fileName=md5(uniqid()).'.'.$file->guessExtension();
    $file->move($this->getParameter('image_directory'), $fileName);
}
```

Comment: var_dump($file) = string(0) ""

Comment: @LuisRosario Problem on your side. Most likely, you don't have permissions to write the current folder.Check this: [Which permissions should be for symfony 3 folders and files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48501277/which-permissions-should-be-for-symfony-3-folders-and-files/48501594#48501594). Also, have you checked if the file is on your server?