# How to keep 777 on var/cache/prod (Symfony 5)

Tags: symfony

I'm using Symfony 5. When I clear the cache, the var/cache/prod folder loses permission 777. On my production server, if the var/cache/prod folder is not in 777, I cannot send a form (error 500).

How can I fixed that ?

Comment: 777 is not recommanded anyway... What is your web user and web group? Do you have control over your server?

Comment: Have you read the documentation? Giving it 777 permission is not the recommended way to give it write access.

Comment: What's the exact error message when you receive that error 500?

Comment: What you most likely needs is this link: [Which permissions should be for symfony 3 folders and files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48501277/which-permissions-should-be-for-symfony-3-folders-and-files/48501594#48501594). It works the same with Symfony 4, Symfony 5, and any other web project. If you don't have control over your server (root access), you will need to ask the one who administrate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a group for the directory creator to which the process running php scripts belongs and give rights to write to the second var of this group.

If you use php-fpm with default settings, then you need to add www-data groups for the user who owns the project directory and set permissions as in the example.

```
usermod -a -G www-data you_user_name
chmod 664 /path_to_you_project/var
```